# Flutter Firebase ,SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17020 null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need some help. I'm trying to authenticate with Firebase using my mobile phone, but I'm not receiving any text messages at all.
Here are the codes.

I did

1. I have enabled phone sign-in on Firebase,
2. registration of the SHA-1 and SHA-256 digital mark.
3. Project is connected with firebase
4. google-services.json file is added to the Project
5. I had seen how the try/catch statement works, but it just passed by.

I didn't

1. I ever didn't receive any messege from firebase.
2. i didn't found any error messege except on that

```
    try {
      await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+82 00000000000',
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          print('verificationCompleted');
          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) async {
          print('verificationFailed message $e');
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
          print('codeSent');
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) async {
          print('codeAutoRetrievalTimeout');
        },
      );
      print('passed');
    } catch (e) {
      print('error message $e');
    }
```

```
  firebase_core: ^2.27.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.9
```

Comment: For the sake of others who might encounter a similar error, I'm leaving a note. Eventually, I decided to reset, and it turned out to be a configuration issue. I suspect that during attempts to resolve the error, I might have inadvertently copied and pasted things into build.gradle or other Android documents.

And I spent a day struggling to resolve this. I just wanted to mention this to anyone who might encounter a similar error in the future.